# How to access dispatch method of multiple contexts in React Context API hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have an app with multiple contexts:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SettingsProvider>
        <ContentProvider>
          <Component />
        </ContentProvider>
      </SettingsProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And I have set up Redux-like store with React Context API, with dispatch methods in reducers. My both provider are set up like this:

```
import reducer from './reducers';

export const SettingsContext = createContext();

function SettingsProvider({ children, userSettings }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    reducer,
    _.merge(defaultSettings, JSON.parse(userSettings)),
  );

  return (
    <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</SettingsContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now I need to access dispatch method of both providers from a component, but it throws an error... Please see a code with comments below:

```
function Settings() {
    // This works in most components, which need to access only one context
    const {state, dispatch} = React.useContext(ContentContext);

    // This method works for accessing multiple contxest
    const settings = React.useContext(SettingsContext);   // accessable as settings.state
    const content = React.useContext(ContentContext);     // content.state.

    // but now this is throwing an error that settings and dispatchSettings are undefined..
    const {settings, dispatchSettings} = React.useContext(SettingsContext);   // accessable as settings.state
    const {content, dispatchContent} = React.useContext(ContentContext);     // content.state.

}
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: I understand that probable answer is: reduce your components into smaller pieces and rearrange your store, so only one store is needed per component. But nevertheless, how one would access dispatch reducer for two or more stores in react component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use renaming with object destructuring e.g.

```
const { dispatch } = useContext(DefaultContext);
const { dispatch: altDispatch } = useContext(AltContext);
```

Dispatch for DefaultContext is now accessible with `dispatch` and AltContext with `altDispatch`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have to rename the dispatch variable .

```
    function SettingsProvider({ children, userSettings }) {
       const [state, dispatchSettings] = useReducer(
       reducer,
       _.merge(defaultSettings, JSON.parse(userSettings)),
    );

    return (
      <SettingsContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatchSettings }}> 
          {children} 
      </SettingsContext.Provider>
          );
```

Same approach will be used for ContentProvider reducer.